# Express app use after DB callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express-4

I'm using [mysql-orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-orm) in a Nodejs Express app this is my code:

**app.js:**

```
// ... all variables are initialized
var orm = null;
var app = express();

db.create(dbSchema, dbSeeds, dbOptions, function(err, ormObject) {
    if (err) throw err;
    orm = ormObject;
});

var coursesRoutes = require('./routes/dashboard/courses')(orm);
app.use('/dashboard/courses', coursesRoutes);
```

**/routes/dashboard/courses.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(orm) {

    router.get('/listall', function(req, res, next) {
        orm.loadMany('sections', null, function(err, sections) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.jsonp(sections);
        });
    });
    return router;
};
```

And this returns this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadMany' of null

I know that the problem is that `orm` variable is passed to file before it is initialized in the `db.create` callback but I don't know how to solve this.

I tried to put:

```
var coursesRoutes = require('./routes/dashboard/courses')(orm);
app.use('/dashboard/courses', coursesRoutes);
```

inside the callback but it returns 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Your courses function is getting called before db connection is established.

This should do the trick.

```
var orm = null;
var app = express();

db.create(dbSchema, dbSeeds, dbOptions, function(err, ormObject) {
    if (err) throw err;
    orm = ormObject;
    var coursesRoutes = require('./routes/dashboard/courses')(orm);
    app.use('/dashboard/courses', coursesRoutes);
});
```

Comment: this returns 404 not found